# How to upgrade firmware in STM32?

Tags: upgrade, bootloader, stm32

Heelo all,

I think it might be silly question.

I am using STM32F2XXX series of controller. I want to upgrade my firmware. My new firmware will be stored in RAM of the controller.

So if i want to use this  new firmware and upgrade the firmware of the device, What are the changes i need to do in bootloader code?

Thanks

Comment: If you store your firmware in RAM, you will need to reprogram it every time you turn the power on. RAM is volatile.

Comment: I will not store my firmware in RAM everytime. Only WHen I have a new firmware which i have to receive from other device(over the air programing).After I receive this firmware in RAM, I have to upgrade my firmware. Any help if i could get on this is appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan on receiving this firmware? USART, CAN, etc.? Do you know which version of the bootloader you are using? V2.x, V3.x, etc.? Please provide as much information as possible so that we can properly help you.

Comment: Have you solved it? If so, could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/27/38/37/58/c2/8c/40/07/DM00161366.pdf/files/DM00161366.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00161366.pdf). BUT be warned: the F2 series has flash sizes ranging from 128KB to 1MB  but the internal RAM is only 128KB so you'll need to implement a offsite storage location for you program. Because it won't fit inside your RAM.